# Combine multiple rows into one row for the Counter name then sum up volumne

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, mongoose

I'd like to combine multiple rows of repeating **Stock Counters** into a single row and also sum up the **Volumne** and **Price** of the combined items so they are stored and displayed to the React Admin list.

Screenshot of the current list of items

[image: Data List]

The output of the below screenshot is run by the below code

```
try {
        const m = await Portfolio.find({}).populate({ path: 'customer', select: 'firstname', model: 'User' }).populate({ path: 'stockItem', select: 'Counter', model: 'Stock Items' }).exec();
        return res
        .setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Total-Count')
        .setHeader('X-Total-Count', Object.keys(m).length)
        .status(201)
        .json(m);
    } catch (err) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.error(`${err}`);
        return res.status(400).json('Failed to either retrieve nor create a Transaction. Kindly retry again.');
    }
```